# Maps address storing problem in arraylist

Tags: android, database, sqlite, maps

I'm working on google maps project.Users can add location and view them on the gridview.When I run my app to view all locations from database,all indexes get retrived from database successfuly and pushed arraylist.But when I try to add location.All previous locations get added database again , then my desired location added end of the array.So when I try to reach desired location from gridview,it shows me first location.I want it to be repeated just once.I think there's problem on my select query.Here's output result.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fla6f.jpg)

```
    GridView gridView= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        MapsActivity.database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Places",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor cursor = MapsActivity.database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM places",null);
        int nameIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
        int latitudeIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude");
        int longitudeIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                nameFromDatabase = cursor.getString(nameIx);
                String latitudeFromDatabase = cursor.getString(latitudeIx);
                String longitudeFromDatabase = cursor.getString(longitudeIx);
                image = cursor.getBlob(3);
                // names.add(nameFromDatabase);
                Double l1 = Double.parseDouble(latitudeFromDatabase);
                Double l2 = Double.parseDouble(longitudeFromDatabase);
                //   System.out.println("coordinates:"+l1+","+l2);
                locationFromDatabase = new LatLng(l1, l2);
                names.add(nameFromDatabase);
                locations.add(locationFromDatabase);
                list.add(new Location(nameFromDatabase, image));

            }

        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter = new LocationListAdapter(this, R.layout.location_items, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your issue is that when adding a new location, your get all the locations again from google maps.

- Your code doesn't include the code for adding a location.

However, you could prevent duplicated data by defining appropriate **UNIQUE** constraints for your **Places** Database.

As an example, based upon your code, you could CREATE the table using :-

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS places (name TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE,longitude REAL,latitude REAL,image BLOB, UNIQUE (longitude,latitude) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)
```

Using `name TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE` will add a restriction/rule/constraint that the name must be unique and if an attempt is made to use a name that already exists (insert or update) then that attempt will be ignored (no error raised).

Using `UNIQUE (longitude,latitude) ON CONFLICT IGNORE` does the same BUT for the combination of BOTH columns.

e.g. if a row in the table has latitude 1 and longitude 1 then :-

- an attempt to add a row with latitude 1 and longitude 1 will result in the attempt being ignored.
- an attempt to add a row with latitude 2 and longitude 1 will work as the combination of the two values has not been used.
- likewise, an attempt to add a row with latitude 1 and longitude 2 will work.